# How do I keep my website looking consistent when re-scaling the browser site

Tags: html, css

My website has a header and a footer with an image as the background in the body just for reference. When I make the browser small, for example in portrait (the height of the screen with a narrow width), the whole website can be seen but scaled down only covering the top half of the browser and there is white blank space on the bottom half of the  browser. There is an image covering the center of the website, which I though was the issue so instead I used the background image property of css but that didn't fix the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is too broad...

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, add this to the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It makes your website reponsive. There are whole books about responsiveness, so I won't try to explain it in a few sentences here, but you'll find a lot of stuff when you search for that term on the net...